# Convert list into tuple then add this tuple into list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I want my output to be

```
add_sizes(['hello', 'world']) -> [('hello', 5), ('world', 5)]
```

but I'm getting

```
add_sizes(['hello', 'world']) -> [('hello', 5), ('hello', 5, 'helloworld', 5)]
```

My code is

```
def add_sizes(strings):

    s = ()
    t=[]
    m=[]
    for i in strings:
        x=i
        for i,c in enumerate(list(x)):
            t.append(c)
        l=(str(''.join(t)),i+1)
        s += l
        m.append(s)
    print(m)
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated thanks

Comment: I think you're over-complicating it a bit. You just need tuples containing every string in `strings` along with the `len()` of the string. Append these, one by one, to a list and return/print the list when you're done. Your `enumerate` and `l=(str(''.join(t)),i+1)` statements aren't necessary

Comment: The cause of your issue is where you have `s=();t=[]` (should be inside the loop) but as eugene y says, the better solution is a list comprehension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> def add_sizes(strings):
...     return [(s, len(s)) for s in strings]
... 
>>> 
>>> add_sizes(['hello', 'world'])
[('hello', 5), ('world', 5)]
```

Or if you want to do it in-place:

```
>>> def add_size(strings):
...     for i, s in enumerate(strings):
...         strings[i] = (s, len(s))
...     return strings
... 
>>> add_sizes(['hello', 'world'])
[('hello', 5), ('world', 5)]
```

Comment: thanks it works like a charm, I didn't know that we can do it this way. much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Someone already gave a complete solution so I'll just post mine too:

```
def add_sizes(strings):
    l = []
    for string in strings:
        l.append((string, len(string)))
    return l

def add_sizes(strings):
    return [(s, len(s)) for s in strings]
```